# Close JFame from addActionListener of a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

How can I invoke `setVisible(false)` of JFrame within `addActionListener` function of a JButton (like below) :

```
jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
   //here           
  }
});
```

Comment: 1) Look into `JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have a variable declared like:

```
JFrame frame;
```

you just need to call:

```
frame.setVisible(false);
```

Otherwise, if you are inside a class that extends `JFrame`, you have to:

```
NameOfClass.this.setVisible(false);
```

Or even better that using `setVisible(false)`, you ca `dispose()` it.

Answer (score 2):

You just need the frame accessible in the spot where your button's action is defined.  You can do this by making the `JFrame` final, or by making it a field in the class where the `Action` is defined:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CloseFrame extends JPanel{

    public CloseFrame(final JFrame frame){

        JButton button = new JButton("Hide Screen");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //What you asked for:
                frame.setVisible(false);
                // What you should use instead of the above:
                //frame.dispose(); 
            }});

        add(button);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new CloseFrame(frame));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Also please note that you should probably use `JFrame.dispose()` if you really are trying to close the application.

Comment: thanks, my situation is that I have a class that extends JFrame, so _Dan_ has the right answer (+1)